# Can I recover lost information about an S3 multipart upload?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In this [multipart upload example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LLuploadFileDotNet.html), one needs to save the upload ID and a set of etags corresponding to each uploaded part until the upload is "closed."  If I lose my upload ID, I guess I can recover it by looking through open multipart uploads with [ListMultipartUploads](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LLlistMPuploadsDotNet.html), but **what if I lose an etag?**  Can those be recovered somehow, or must I abort the whole transfer and start over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have retrieved the upload ID from ListMultipartUploads, you can then use ListParts to get the list of parts (and their etags) that have been completed for this upload.  You can use this information to then restart your upload from the last completed part.

[Multipart Upload API and Permissions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuAndPermissions.html)

[Example of resuming multipart uploads using AWS SDK for iOS](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=100323&tstart=0)